# How to trigger error state including md-error

Tags: angular, angular-material2

`passwordInvalid` is a boolean that I would expect to be able to use to toggle the error state of the md-input.

I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
<md-input-container [error]="passwordInvalid" >
     <input name="password" tabindex="1" required mdInput 
   placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" value="{{user.password}}">
     <md-error >Invalid login</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

When `passwordInvalid` is true, the error state including showing the md-error would be toggled. When it goes back to false, it would return to a valid state.

Currently my ghetto work around:

```
<md-input-container [class.mat-input-invalid]="passwordInvalid" >
     <input name="password" tabindex="1" required mdInput placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" value="{{user.password}}">
     <md-error [class.mat-input-error]="passwordInvalid">Invalid login</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

The `md-error` component/directive appears if they try to submit without entering anything because the field is required. When `passwordInvalid` is true, the styling works on the container but the `md-error` component/directive will not appear.

Is there something I'm missing from the docs?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using async validator that accepts the `passwordInvalid` value and sets an error to the input. See [the working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gmRMyhO4bdShQXFIwtHy?p=preview).
Click the `passwordInvalid` toggler to change its value and then start typing or hit the button to see the error.

**my.validator.ts**

```
import {Directive, OnInit, forwardRef, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors} from '@angular/forms';
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

@Directive({
    selector: '[myValidator][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyValidator), multi: true },
    ]
})
export class MyValidator implements OnInit, Validator, OnChanges {
    @Input('myValidator')
    public myValidator: boolean;

    errors$: BehaviorSubject<ValidationErrors | null> = new BehaviorSubject<ValidationErrors | null>(null);

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errors$.next(this.myValidator);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        changes.myValidator && this.errors$.next(changes.myValidator.currentValue);
    }

    validate(c: AbstractControl) {
        return this.errors$.asObservable().map(value => {
            let obj = c.errors || {};
            if (value) obj.myValidator = value;
            else delete obj['myValidator'];
            if (!Object.keys(obj).length) obj = null;
            c.setErrors(obj);
            console.log('obj', obj)
            return obj;
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
    <md-input-container>
        <input name="password" tabindex="1" required mdInput 
               [myValidator]="passwordInvalid"  #password="ngModel"
               placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" value="{{user.password}}">
        <md-error *ngIf="password.errors?.required" >Field is required</md-error>
        <md-error *ngIf="password.errors?.myValidator">passwordInvalid</md-error>

        {{ password.errors|json }}
    </md-input-container>
```